# fread like functionality for reading from an arbitrary stream

Tags: c, stream, fread

I am creating a library which parses a binary file format.

There are two functions:

```
void* read_buf(const void* buf, size_t size);
void* read(const char* filename);
```

In my `read` method I plan to read a file till EOF and pass the buffer obtained to `read_buf`. But in C, there are no stream or buffer handling functions analogous to `fread()` for such user created buffers. Basically, I want `io.BytesIO` (Python) or `BinaryReader` (C#) functionality.

EDIT: Only cross platform solutions please

Comment: It's not clear from this why you need a generic stream mechanism. Use `malloc()` to create the buffer that you pass to `read_buf()`.

Comment: @Barmar I want to advance the pointer like fread does, but on a buffer I created by reading the file

Comment: Create a `struct` that contains a buffer pointer and index. Then increment the index.

Comment: What size are the files?  Can you use memory mapping?

Comment: Maybe `fmemopen()` or `open_memstream()` will be useful if you're on a system like Linux that supports them.

Comment: _Side note:_ `read` conflicts with the standard syscall `read`. Rename it to (e.g.) `read_file`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The file size aren't a concern, however I want to get stream-like features so I don't accidentally re-read a portion of the buffer

Comment: @Barmar I would essentially need to reimplement the `FILE` struct, since I need seek, tell features. I would also need to reimplement `read` itself.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. `stdio` is not designed to support custom streams.

Comment: Shawn's idea may be best. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html

Comment: @Barmar I myself work on Windows and I want cross platform support that's why I am sticking to the standard library. Do you know of any 3rd party library which might have this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if the POSIX functions [`fmemopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) and [`open_memstream`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) are available on your system:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fmemopen(void *buf, size_t size, const char *mode);
FILE *open_memstream(char **ptr, size_t *sizeloc);
```

`fmemopen` returns a `FILE *` that you can use with `fread` and other standard stream functions.

These functions specified in the POSIX standard are available on many systems. There are some ports available for Windows, either stand alone of via POSIX compatibility layers such as [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Implementing a generic layer to simulate standard stream functions on memory buffer is tricky if you want more than `fread()`, I strongly recommend you use a standard approach and use a compatibility layer where POSIX support is flaky or incomplete.

**EDIT:** For your parsing task, instead of using the POSIX functions above, you should probably write your own parsing functions, which will give you an opportunity to design a better interface than the standard stream functions such as `fread` and `fscanf`. You can define a structure with a pointer to an array that the `open` or `load` function will allocate and initialize from the file contents and some  context data such as the current offset, total size... for individual parsing functions to update as they read and decode the binary data. Cross platform code must work with both classes of endianness, honor alignment constraints, handle varying integer type sizes... Also avoid naming your function `read` as this name is used for a standard system call on POSIX systems.

Comment: This can't be an option, I use MSVC and Windows. I don't want to switch to a different compiler just to get a POSIX feature

Comment: I didn't find a single 3rd party library which implements streams. Is it that unheard of in C? How do other parsers deal with it, considering many binary format parsers are implemented in C?

Comment: @demberto: If you have specific platform requirements, say so in the question.  You can't just add new requirements after you've been given a probably workable answer that happens not to fit the platform you didn't state you were using.

Comment: @demberto: Clearly, what you are seeking to do is not standard — I don't know what you mean by streams.  In C, a `FILE *` is a file stream, so you need to identify what's different about what you're referring to compared with normal file streams.  I'm still not clear why a regular file stream won't do what you want.  Windows has a huge API — you may be able to find what you're after in it, somewhere.  If not, you're going to have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @demberto: you say *I myself work on Windows and I want cross platform support that's why I am sticking to the standard library* The problem with this platform is its  plethoric API riddled with quirks rooted in legacy choices. It is difficult to write cross platform code with MSVC on Windows, this compiler keeps insisting on using the so called *secure* functions, which are implemented with APIs that are not compatible with the ones included in the C Standard.

Comment: @demberto:  For your parsing problem, you should probably define a structure with a pointer to the memory block holding the file data and some parsing context and define functions that will update this structure while producing parsed items as you go. Avoid naming your function `read` as this name is used for a standard system call on POSIX systems.

Comment: @chqrlie I can disable those warnings with a single macro definition `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This answer was given 2 after I said in a comment below the question that I need cross platform support, my bad I didn't edit the question.

Comment: @demberto: yes you can! you seem experienced enough to write an appropriate platform independent parser...

Comment: @demberto: no, it is probably not difficult, albeit you do not give any hint about the file format. Cross platform code must work with both classes of endianness, honor alignment constraints, handle varying integer type sizes... Using stream functions would probably be a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @chqrlie Its a propreitary format called flp, I have already written a parser in Python. I want to create a shell extension around it, so I tried C++ but got lost in the templates and variants. So I am hoping C will make it possible somehow. The format itself is little endian. And `#pragma push` willl have its alternatives

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245740/discussion-between-demberto-and-chqrlie), please so is bugging me about it